# DataTables API methods not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to set up an extremely basic DataTables example. After initializing the table with DataTables, why are some of the API methods not available?  Am I missing something as far as how it's supposed to be used?

Here's a simple jsfiddle where I initialize the table, and then try to retrieve the first row.  However, it doesn't look the like `row()` method exists:

http://jsfiddle.net/LEWQU/

Here's the javascript in the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myDataTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
   console.log(myDataTable.row(0));
});
```

Developer console shows the following error referring to the `console.log` line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Authorization required to load the jquery.dataTables.min.js and the jquery-2.0.3.min.js files.

Comment: Sorry about that @bloodyKnuckles, it's all fixed now.

Comment: For this simple example, this is pulling up the rows: `myDataTable[0].rows`, and cells can be got: `myDataTable[0].rows[0].cells`.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
var myDataTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
```

to

```
var myDataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

Comment: "It is important to note the difference between $( selector ).DataTable() and $( selector ).dataTable(). The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object." https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. authorization is required to load jquery datatables (as bloodyknuckles pointed out too)
2. the method is "dataTable()" and not "DataTable()"

Comment: According to the documentation, the `DataTable()` returns an instance of the API, while `dataTable()` returns a jquery object, but both are valid ways to instantiate a datatable: http://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to use the correct version of DataTable (1.9.4), and updated the code to use the `dataTable` method.  I am still not able to call the `row()` method.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Still not really sure what the issue was, but updating to the newest version of DataTables seems to have worked.